# Convert Jquery standard date and time to FullCalendar js date object

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a standard Jquery date picker which shows 2 textboxes.
One textbox has the date like so: 15/11/2011.
The other textbox shows the time like so: 13:15.

Combining the values will give me 15/11/2011 13:15.

I want to be able to render an event using fullcalendar using that string (15/11/2011 13:15).
I'm stumped whether to use a jquery date picker format function, somehow squeeze this into a new Js data object or use some date library to do the conversion.

What is the best way to achieve it?  When passing the date to fullcalendar plugin it states the date object must be like so:

*

> When specifying Event Objects for events or eventSources, you may
>   specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"),
>   a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX
>   timestamp.

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I've basically sent the date to the server for persistence and then re-fetch the events.  I let FullCalendar work out the date by pulling the date from a Json list.  This saves having to trying to convert the date and then add it to the calendar on an individual event basis.